# How to mount postgres backup into the postgres container running

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-volume

```
docker run -d --rm --name dummy -v postgres_volume:/root alpine tail -f /dev/null
docker cp ./data dummy:/root
docker stop dummy
docker run -p 5432:5432 -v postgres_volume:/var/lib/postgresql -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres
```

The above commands giving error: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/postgresql’: Permission denied.`

`./data` in the docker cp command contains the Postgres backup.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You (or rather postgres) are missing permissions for the files you have copied. This should fix it:

```sh
docker run --rm -v postgres_volume:/var/lib/postgresql postgres /bin/sh -c \
'chown --recursive $(id -u postgres):$(id -g postgres) /var/lib/postgresql'
```

Comment: Didnt work. The container is exiting. the data folder has current user permission

Comment: @m9m9m is `./data` a directory or a postgres dump file?

Comment: ./data is the backup from another Postgres container. It has pg_ folders inside

Comment: @m9m9m I meant how it was made. Did you just copy `/var/lib/postgresql/data` from another instance or did you use `pg_dump`?

Comment: copied  /var/lib/postgresql/data

Comment: @m9m9m Then  I'm unable to reproduce the problem. Check how the mounted directory looks inside the container. Override default command when running  postgresq as you did with alpine image, then get inside with `docker exec -it <container_name> bash`. Use `stat` and `ls` to examine the directory once inside.